# Spyder 5.3.3 crashes on startup, while loading environment

Tags: environment-variables, spyder

Spyder 5.3.3 on Redhat8, Anaconda3, crashes while loading environment variables:

...
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/plugins/pythonpath/utils.py", line 31, in get_system_pythonpath
env = get_user_env()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/utils/environ.py", line 71, in get_user_env
env_dict = get_user_environment_variables()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/utils/environ.py", line 63, in get_user_environment_variables
k, v = kv.split('=', 1)
^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

As a workaround, if I downgrade to an older spyder-kernels=2.3.3, then the environment variables are handled correctly. But spyder-kernels=2.4.1 create the error, which crashes the startup.

Tried to install a startup.py file to load the environment:
import os
os.environ['test']='test value'
hoping that it was an empty set that was causing the problem. No effect.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like a clumsy implementation for reading the environment variables in the function get_user_environment_variables(), which will fail on environment variable values with newline characters in there.

Same problem here.

Edit the file (in your case) /home/user/anaconda3/envs/p311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/spyder/utils/environ.py

and change the `get_user_environment_variables()` function to read:

```
def get_user_environment_variables():
    """
    Get user environment variables from a subprocess.

    Returns
    -------
    env_var : dict
        Key-value pairs of environment variables.
    """
    return dict(os.environ.items())
```

Or wait until this Spyder bug is fixed.